# Forward all requests to one index.php file, for non-existing files, but *including* the index.php itself

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So I have this quite typical "single point of entry" config in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And it works fine. Now - I also what that behavior on the request to the index.php file itself. So I do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#file must not exist:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [or]

# *unless* this is the index.php *itself*, then I also 
#want to pass it to itself. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So we have kind of exception here - go on when file doesn't exist but also when it exists but it's the 'index.php'.

And it works, but unfortunately it also works for files deeper in the structure. What I want is to catch only the 'index.php' being on the same level as the .htaccess itself.

**Update:** 
Maybe I should clarify. I want to create a very generic, out of the box single point of entry for php, like this one:

https://github.com/kpion/point1

It "works", but I feel I should do it a bit differently. I already asked a similar question ( [The utlimate way to make a single entry point (front controller) working with the most common web server setups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536917/the-utlimate-way-to-make-a-single-entry-point-front-controller-working-with-th) ) but was considered as "too long" so this is my second approach :)

Please bear in mind, that I can't use ^/index.php - in the condition, because the 'request uri doesn't really need to start with it. This htaccess can be *deeper* as well, i.e. deeper in the document root. This is actually quite common, when I have many small projects in /var/www/html and I don't want to create a vhost for everything. So the "root" is /var/www/html and now:

Example:

The project is located in 
/var/www/html/point/point1

The .htaccess is inside it. It forwards all requests to non-existing files to the index.php. With my few additional lines, it also forwards itself to the index.php.

**Note**: %{REQUEST_URI} in this case, when we open /var/www/html/point/point1 is equal to "/point/point1/index.php"

It is **not** /index.php

It works fine, when I call http://localhost/point/point1/.local/noExistinFile or http://localhost:82/point/point1/ (this will point to index.php, which will be matched by my last RewriteCond).

But, when I have a file located in /var/www/html/point/point1/.local/index.php and I call http://localhost2/point/point1/.local/index.php - I **don't** want this to pass the conditions and I don't want it to be forwarded to index.php.

So I need something **relative** to the .htaccess location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I forgot I asked this question. For anyone interested: I found out the solution is quite simple:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# lets forward the index.php itself as well, to be later consistent in how we handle things:
RewriteRule ^(index.php)$ index.php?url=index.php [QSA,L]
```

The last line does the job, because:

1. The RewriteCond above obviously does not apply (by default they only work for the "RewriteRule" directly below). So the -f (must not exist) doesn't apply, which is cool.
2. Now the key part: the **tested string** in the RewriteRule **is** a file/dir **relative** to the directory .htaccess is in. So, if the .htaccess file is inside /var/www/html/point/point1 and we request:

   http://whateverHostWeSetPointingToThisDir/index.php then the string being tested in RewriteRule is exactly "index.php". And when we request

   http://localhost/point/point1/blah/index.php then, assuming the ...point1 points to our 'point1' dir, what is tested is exactly "blah/index.php".

This is why RewriteRule ^(index.php)$ matches the 'index.php' file being in the same directory as the .htaccess itself. Regardless the host name, or the parent directory name, or anything.

By the way: if we request http://whateverHostWeSetPointingToThisDir then this will work as well if we have set DirectoryIndex index.php but that's not really related.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#file must not exist:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [or]
#or is /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, but... no. it can't work in my case  :( This is something I tried before, and it *would* work indeed, if the directory the index.php is in, was in the same time a 'document root'. Which is not the case. That is the whole problem I've been having since a few days now o.O. There are many projects under /var/www/html. This is quite typical in dev environment, right? I don't want to make a vhost for every single small project. So I have many of them, and for example one is in /var/www/html/point/point1 and there is the .htaccess located, and then %{REQUEST_URI} == /point/point1/index.php

Comment: So the ^/index.php$ will not match it, unfortunately. So this "condition check" must be done somehow in the context of htaccess location.  I updated my question as well.